# How to combine these two functions with one that uses an optional parameter?

Tags: python, function

The following two functions are almost identical:

```
def http_get(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as w:
        return w.read()

def http_post(url, params):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, params) as w:
        return w.read()
```

Can I use variable length argument lists or optional parameters to combine these so that I can call it with either one parameter or two, and have it do the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
def http_get(url, params=None):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, params) as w:
        return w.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're passing all the arguments directly, you could argue that you should just use `*args`.

```
def http_get(*args):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(*args) as w:
        return w.read()

http_post = http_get
```